# Use multiple ImageViews as background

Tags: java, android, background, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm currently working on an app for 2 'players', the layout contains the same controls on top and (rotated) bottom.
I use an image as background to display it for both players:
[image: Background]

Blue represents player one, red represents player two. Grey is for settings.
I used this until now, but I want the players to be able to change their background color.

My attempt was to put imageViews in the background,  containing the selected color. But how can I put them in the background so my other views won't be affected? And how can I add multiple of them? I thought I could add two ImageViews to my RelativeLayout, the first one taking up 45% of parent space from top, and the second one from the bottom. The background itself would be grey for the center (for example).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks! that woks for me. but I have to admit that I don't fully understand why: 1. I suppose the 'layout_above/below is used for aligning the views and giving both the same height. But why are the layouts per default in background of the other views of the relativeLayout? And 2. I still have a border (white frame) around the layouts that I didn't had with my background. Is that caused by something like a default margin of the layouts? How do I get rid of that?

Comment: About 1. I don't understand the question :) and 2. This code has not white margins, have you done some modifications? can you post it?

Comment: sorry, 2nd was my own fault, there was a padding set in my relativeLayout. First was, why the linearLayouts are automatically in the background of the relativeLayout and not blocking/displaying over my existing views

Comment: If I understand you well, the answer should be that these images are childs of a parent, and the childs are showed over the parents

Comment: Okay, that's what I meant. Thank you very much!